# list() function won't separate string into characters

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def map():
  myList = ['g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle             gr gl             zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr\'q ufw rfgq     rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb.           lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.']
  list(myList)
  print(myList)
```

Why does `list()` function does not separate list into characters? But if I put this way then it works:

```
list('g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle             gr gl            zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr\'q ufw rfgq     rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb.           lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.')
```

Comment: Because you're giving it a single-element list to iterate over. Why are you calling `list` with a list argument? Also, don't call your own function `map`; that's a built-in function.

Comment: For `myList` it has the type of `list([[char]])` and your second example is `list([char])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing to note here is that strings are, themselves, <s>lists</s> iterables, collecting characterstogether. What `list()` does is take each element of one list/iterable and put it into another list. The effect this has on a string is to make another list containing every character of that string (because `list()` isn't going to re-combine all those characters into a string again).

In your first line, however, you're not giving it a string - you're giving it a list that contains a string. `list()` will look at the input, see that the first item is an entire string, and move that whole string to another list. That's why it doesn't get split up. If you instead had:

```
myList = 'g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle             gr gl             zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr\'q ufw rfgq     rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb.           lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.'
```

Then you would get the behavior you expect.

Comment: strings are not lists.  strings are iterable though.  Lists take an iterable as a parameter.

Comment: @Gerrat whoops, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

myList is an iterable, so the list constructor will iterate throught the elements in the list. In your case there is one string in the list. Lose the square brackets when you declare myList to get the behavior you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The function `list()` only goes one layer deep when creating a list out of the argument.

When you pass it a list with one element, it will observe the list with one element, and put the list into a new list.

When you pass it a string, it will observe a list of characters and put each character into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

`list` takes sequences in its constructor. You assign `myList` with a literal list object containing a single string element. When you call `list(myList)` its argument is already a list so the one element is extracted and referenced in a new list object. When you call `list` with a string as the argument, it interprets that as its sequence to "listify" and separates them by element - the individual characters from the string.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to split them.

```
def map():
    myList = ['g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle             gr gl             zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr\'q ufw rfgq     rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb.           lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.']
    print list(myList[0].split())
```

myList[0] access the first element of your list, which is the whole string. split() then basically just splits them up into characters. I think it is then already returned as list, but to make sure it is a list, just put the 'list()' thingy around it.